# How can I prove that the sequence $P_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^j}x^j$ is Cauchy? and converges to g.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

[image]

1- Why the author choose this type of polynomials to show that the inner product of all polynomials with the given inner product is not complete?

2-How can I prove that the sequence $P_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^j}x^j$ is Cauchy?

3-Why $P_{n} \rightarrow g$?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: It converges for $|x| < 2$

Comment: For a given positive $\epsilon$ and an $x$ satisfying $|x|<2$ can you find a positive integer $m$ such that $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{m+n}<\epsilon$ for any $n>0$?

Comment: I think you mean inside the norm ..... right?@JohnWaylandBales

Comment: No, I can not find that positive integer m, because always I have an $x$, so what shall I do? could you help me please? @JohnWaylandBales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (\frac{x}{2})^j$ is a Geometric series, which is known to converge when $|\frac{x}{2}| < 1$.

We are given that $x \in [0, 1]$, so $P_n$ converges. And since $P_n$ converges, it is Cauchy.

2) $g$ is the closed-form expression for the value of a Geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

The series is alternating for $x<0$ so if it is Cauchy on some positive interval it is Cauchy on the corresponding negative interval. So assume $0\le x<2$. Show that the series is Cauchy for $x$.

Let $0<\epsilon<1$ and let $m>\dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln\left(x/2\right)}$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
m\ln\left(x/2\right)&<&\ln(\epsilon)\\
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m&<&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Let $n>0$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{m+n}&=&\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n\right)\\
&<&\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m\cdot1\\
&<&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Note: This is the answer I prepared for the original version of the question.

Comment: Why the author choose this type of polynomials to show that the inner product of all polynomials with the given inner product is not complete? could you please explain this for me?

Comment: In order for the given polynomial space to be complete, every Cauchy sequence of polynomials must converge to a polynomial in the space. But  the given Cauchy sequence of polynomials does not converge to a polynomial. It converges to to the rational function $g(x)=\dfrac{2}{2-x}$ which is NOT a polynomial.